# how to create an array of list of pair in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I want to use an array of list of pairs to represent a directed weighted graph using adjacent list

```
class Graph{
int n_v;
list<pair<int, int> > *adj;
public:
Graph(int _n_v){
    n_v = _n_v;
    adj = new list<pair<int, int> >[n_v];
}
```

but the compiler raised an error:

```
class list<pair<int, int>> is not compatible with list<int, int>>
```

how to solve with this problem?

Comment: You solve this problem by first posting a [mcve], instead of fake code.

Comment: Read your error message very carefully, and look at the exact types it actually talks about -- not just what you _expect_ it to say.

Comment: @ sorry . I have updated my question

Comment: If that's the *exact* error message from your compiler, it's not only wrong, it's *broken*. There is an extra `>` on the end of the line. You have not included a minimal, **complete** verifiable example, so the very best we can do is a wag (wild-ass-guess). *Assuming* you included the correct standard headers, *assuming* you have some `using` statements to bring `list` and `pair` into namespace, *assuming* there is a closing `};` after your class, and *assuming* a simple instantiation in some `main()`, [your code compiles and works](http://ideone.com/8UAHiP). Post a MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector` especially if you use standard containers already:

```
std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, int>>> arr( size );
```

Comment: it works . But I don't know the reason why using an array to store a list of pair raise an error.

Comment: @Hungryfool if you want to know that provide [mcve] and exact error message

Answer (score 0):

try this, so simple and easy:

```
std::pair <int, int> pair_array[MAX_NUMBER];

for(int i=0; i<MAX_NUMBER; ++i)
{
  //...
  func(i,a,b);
}

void func(int i, int a, int b)
{
  pair_array[i] = std::make_pair(a,b);
}
```

Comment: thank you . But this is not what i want . I have updated my question.